# Imprimir todas as condições if

Tags: python

Queria um modo que quando o usuário digitasse a key = 4, todas as condições que eu atribui fossem impressas, tem algum modo ou eu teria que atribuir uma condição if e repetir tudo novamente?

```
import math
import sys

print()
print("#" * 51)
print("Este programa calculará o SENO, COSSENO e TANGENTE.")
print("#" * 51)
print()

lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

a = int(input("Para realizar os cálculos digite: \n\nSENO = 1 \nCOSSENO = 2 \nTANGENTE = 3 \nTODOS = 4 \nENCERRAR PROGRAMA = 5 \n\nDigite a seguir: "))
print("#" * 51)
print()
 
while a not in lista1:
        print("Ei, digite um dos números informados!")
        print()
        a = int(input("Para realizar os cálculos digite: \n\nSENO = 1 \nCOSSENO = 2 \nTANGENTE = 3 \nTODOS = 4 \nENCERRAR PROGRAMA = 5 \n\nDigite a seguir: "))
        print("#" * 51)
        print()

if a == 1:
    co = float(input("Digite o valor do CATETO OPOSTO: "))
    hi = float(input("Digite o valor da HIPOTENUSA: "))
    print("#" * 51)
    print()
                  
    sen = co / hi

    print(f"O valor do SENO é igual à {round(sen, 3)}!")
    print()
    
if a == 2:
    ca = float(input("Digite o valor do CATETO ADJACENTE: "))
    hi = float(input("Digite o valor da HIPOTENUSA: "))
    print("#" * 51)
    print()
                  
    cos = ca / hi

    print(f"O valor do COSSENO é igual à {round(cos, 3)}!")
    print()

if a == 3:
    co = float(input("Digite o valor do CATETO OPOSTO: "))
    ca = float(input("Digite o valor do CATETO ADJACENTE: "))
    print("#" * 51)
    print()
                  
    tan = co / ca

    print(f"O valor da TANGENTE é igual à {round(tan, 3)}!")
    print()

if a == 5:   
    print("Encerrando programa...")
    print()
    sys.exit(0)

#Quando o usuario digitasse a key 4 todos os cáculos seriam impressos
```

Comment: Separe as porções de código específico em função e para cada opção chame a função ou funções relacionada(s).

Comment: Não bastaria adicionar um `or` nas suas condições? `if a == 1 or a == 4`, ou de forma mais simples `if a in {1, 4}`

Comment: @Woss obrigado amigo, ajudou muito, resolveu meu problema

Comment: O ideal seria você fazer uma lógica diferente para o valor 4 mesmo, pois se fizer a chamada novamente dos ifs anteriores irá pedir ao usuário para digitar valores repetidamente.

Answer (score 1):

É uma simples questão de lógica. Se você quer que um código seja executando quando `a = 1` ou quando `a = 4`, basta fazer tal condição.

Hoje você tem:

```py
if a == 1:
  ...
```

Basta fazer:

```py
if a == 1 or a == 4:
  ...
```

Ou, como alternativa, você pode criar um conjunto dos possíveis valores e verificar se o `a` está nesse conjunto:

```py
# testa se a é 1 ou 4
if a in {1, 4}:
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro separe o código recorrente em funções.
Em linguagem de programação a ideia básica de função é encapsular um código que poderá ser invocado/chamado por qualquer outro trecho do programa, ou seja uma função nada mais é do que uma sub-rotina a ser usada em seu programa.

A utilização de funções visa modularizar um sistema podendo dividi-lo em várias partes no qual cada parte realizará uma tarefa bem definida.
Em python definimos uma função com o uso da palavra chave [`def`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).

Como todas as operações realizam o mesmo processamento, coletar dois valores e os dividir, foi criada uma função `calc(opr, l1, l2)` que aceita três parâmetros de texto onde:

- `opr` é o texto a ser exibido informando qual a operação realizada.
- `l1` é o texto a ser exibido informando um dos lados do triangulo a ser operacionalizado.
- `l2` é o texto a ser exibido informando o outro lado do triangulo a ser operacionalizado.

As funções `seno()`, `cosseno()` e `tangente()` apenas chamam `calc()` com os argumentos adequados.

Em seguida melhore simplifique o laço onde serão escolhidas as opções de processamento do sistema, removendo o código verboso pela chamada das respectivas funções para cada opção.

**Para simplificar o exemplo nenhum código de verificação e validação de entrada foi adicionado.**

```
def calc(opr, l1, l2):
  a = float(input(f"Digite o valor do {l1}: "))
  b = float(input(f"Digite o valor da {l2}: "))                
  r = a / b
  print(f"\nO valor do {opr} é igual à {round(r, 3)}!\n{'#' * 51}\n")

def seno():
  calc("SENO", "CATETO OPOSTO", "HIPOTENUSA")
  
def cosseno():
  calc("COSSENO", "CATETO ADJACENTE", "HIPOTENUSA")

def tangente():
  calc("TANGENTE", "CATETO OPOSTO", "CATETO ADJACENTE")

print(f"\n{'#' * 51}\nEste programa calculará o SENO, COSSENO e TANGENTE.\n{'#' * 51}\n")    
while True:
  a = int(input("Para realizar os cálculos digite: \n\nSENO = 1 \nCOSSENO = 2 \nTANGENTE = 3 \nTODOS = 4 \nENCERRAR PROGRAMA = 5 \n\nDigite a seguir: "))
  print(f'{"#" * 51}\n')
  if a == 1:
    seno()
  elif a == 2:
    cosseno()
  elif a == 3:
    tangente()
  elif a == 4: #Quando o usuário digitar 4 todos os cálculos serão realizados.
    seno()
    cosseno()
    tangente()
  elif a == 5:   
    print("Encerrando programa...\n")
    break
  else:
    print("Ei, digite um dos números informados!\n")
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/HospitableBaggyPackage#main.py)</sup>